# adding a check box to php queries table

Tags: php

My Code so far. The data gets pulled correctly

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Request");

echo "<table border='1'>

<tr>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Prayer Request</th>
<th>Deactivate Request</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Reg_F_Name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Reg_L_Name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Reg_Request'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td><input name=\"checkbox[]\" type=\"checkbox\" id=\"checkbox[]\" value=\"".$rows['Reg_ID']. "\" /></td>";  
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>";

mysqli_close($con);

?>

<?php

$del_id = $_POST['checkbox']; 

for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
$del_id = $checkbox[$i];
$sql = "Update Request  set Reg_Status=0 WHERE ='$Reg_ID'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
}


?>
<br /><br />
</div>
```

Nothing Happens when I Click Submit. I am wanting it to Update the reg_Status to 0 for every check box that is click. So whats my problem. Thank you in advance for helping!

Comment: What error do you get? (I am assuming your lack of quotes is just a typo when posting your question)

Comment: If you're getting a parsing error, look closely at the line of code that echoes the `input`.  Stack Overflow's syntax highlighting is showing you a problem with the quotes.

Comment: I am getting an internal server error

Answer (score 1):

You should provide the error message in the future.

This could be a problem in your code:

```
echo "<td>" . <input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="<? echo $rows['Reg_ID'] . "</td>";
```

You have a syntax error right after "". You don't need to end the string here and you have to escape the quotes inside your input element, so that PHP does not confuse them with the end of a string.

```
echo "<td><input name=\"checkbox[]\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"".$rows['Reg_ID']. "\" /></td>";
```

Now I am "connecting" the first part of the string with the value of the $rows['Reg_Id'] variable and the second part of the string. Finally, you should use an id only once inside a single document.

Finally, take a look at the PHP manual:

[Click](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Comment: Thanks i am very new to php. c# and python and vb are the languages i am conferrable in. Learning PHP on the fly for a project.

Comment: Now that is a completely different problem and question. You need to take a look at HTML-forms.

Answer (score 0):

You are havig a while-loop and then:

```
 echo "<td>" . <input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="<? echo $rows['Reg_ID'] . "</td>";
```

But in your case the id is not unique. 
if you have a unique id in your table I would insert this id into the '[]'-brackets.
Furthermore the quotes are not set properly - try it like that:

```
echo '<td><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox['.$rows['Reg_ID'].']" value=".$row[something].'</td>';
```