# Updating data from checkbox clicked

Tags: php, database

My Code so far. The data gets pulled correctly

```
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Request");

echo "<table border='1'>

<tr>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Prayer Request</th>
<th>Deactivate Request</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Reg_F_Name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Reg_L_Name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Reg_Request'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td><input name=\"checkbox[]\" type=\"checkbox\" id=\"checkbox[]\" value=\"".$rows['Reg_ID']. "\" /></td>";  
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

echo 
"<form action='' method='post'> 
<input type='submit' name='use_button' value='Update' /> 
</form>"; 

if(isset($_POST['use_button'])) 
{ 
    echo "hey"; 
$del_id = $_POST['checkbox']; 
$detectinglocations = 'your database table name';

foreach($del_id as $value){
   $sql = "Update Request  set Reg_Status=0 WHERE Reg_ID='".$value."'";
   $result = mysql_query($sql);
}




}

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Nothing Happens when I Click Submit. I am wanting it to Update the reg_Status to 0 for every check box that is click. So whats my problem. Thank you in advance for helping!

Comment: possible duplicate of [adding a check box to php queries table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23110897/adding-a-check-box-to-php-queries-table)

Comment: Why are you asking this again?

Comment: `$result = mysql_query($sql);` <= the culprit; least, one of 'em.

Comment: updated the code a lot was wrong but still not working

Answer (score 0):

try adding an input hidden field with same name as the checkbox name before each checkbox and with value 0 .

The checkbox doesnt get posted when not checked.